# проверка выделенной памяти и лимитом времени

Tags: php

Как проверить сколько памяти и времени выделено для работы скрипта в общем, и сколько было использовано по факту? 
С памятью пробовал играть с `memory_get_peak_usage()` и `memory_get_usage()` но не понял как это работает. Так как в начале скрипта `memory_get_peak_usage()` выдал 311008 а в конце скрипта  `memory_get_usage()` показал 14650736. Наверное я что то делаю не так.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Времени для выполнения скрипта выделено:

```
ini_get('max_execution_time')
```

Если разрешено использовать `set_time_limit` то лимит может быть любой. Напомню, что вызов set_time_limit сбрасывает счётчик ограничения. Проработавший 5 минут скрипт, в котором в цикле стоял `set_time_limit(5)` - запросто.

Плюс интересный момент, что именно понимается под временем исполнения. Зависит от платформы: *nix - исполнение самого скрипта, не включая всякие внешние запросы вроде `curl`. windows - реальное время.

Лимит памяти:

```
ini_get('memory_limit')
```

Тоже может быть изменён во время исполнения.

Затраченное время исполнения: есть в `$_SERVER` ключик `REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT` - метка времени начала работы. Соответственно, затрачено реального времени:

```
microtime(true) - $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT']
```

Но это для отслеживания реального времени. Сколько потрачено самим скриптом, а сколько ожидали какой-нибудь блокирующий ввод-вывод - неизвестно. И ещё одна проблема с тем, что `$_SERVER` не защищён от записи. Любое значение в массиве можно из кода изменить.

Расход памяти:

1. `memory_get_usage` - текущее потребление памяти
2. `memory_get_peak_usage` - пиковое потребление памяти за время работы этого скрипта. (не разрешённое, а реально использованное)

И здесь проблема, но более интересного свойства. Реальный объём затраченной памяти может превышать эти цифры, если память была выделена не непосредственно скрипту, а какому-то библиотечному вызову. Например, на нужды `libxml2` или `libpcre`.

---

Если вам нужно собирать статистику работы приложения - посмотрите в сторону `Pinba`. А так же в форматы логов nginx, php-fpm - у nginx есть `$upstream_response_time` - время, через которое ответил backend, т.е. типично это время работы скрипта и будет.

Если необходимо поискать узкие места конкретного скрипта - `xdebug` или другой профилировщик.